# Tensor ; How can i recognize the type of tensor???

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I want to use Matlab for my project. matlab has tensor toolbox and in it there are two types of tensor : Dens tensor and sparse tensor.
my project is about " fiber orientation". how can i know what type is my tensor and use which one from tensor toolbox in Matlab.
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general a sparse tensor is a tensor with many zeros whereas a dense tensor has no (or hardly any zeros.

So you could check for the number of non-zeros (`nnz(A)`) and compare that to the size of the tensor